# How can I reassign keyboard shortcuts for Skype for Business 365?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, skype-for-business

I recently upgraded to Office 365 from Office 2013.  In the previous version, I was able to use <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> to open Skype for Business.  In the latest version, this shortcut doesn't work.  Instead, I'm stuck with the unbelievably clunky <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>.  How can I reassign <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> to open Skype for Business?